# Not able to set Magento 2.2.2 to production mode

Tags: magento2.2.2, production-mode

I am done with all the work of my website but now when I try to set it to production mode, it abruptly terminates in shell without giving any error details in log file. At least I was not able to identify if it has some useful info that can guide me to troubleshoot.

Here is what I did to achieve it after the command to set in production mode failed:

1. I deleted the content inside the folders "generated", "var/cache", "var/page_cache", "var/tmp" and "var/view_preprocessed".
2. The folder permissions are set as follows:
   generated: 0777

   var/cache:0755

   var/page_cache: 0755

   var/tmp: 0755

   var/view_preprocessed: 0755
3. After deletion of folders, I ran following commands in sequence:

   > php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   >
   > php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -s standard -f
   >
   > php bin/magento cache:flush

   The above three commands run successfully.
4. Now, to set production mode, I ran following command:

   > php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

   This is what I got on shell screen:

   > Enabled maintenance mode
   >   Starting compilation
   >   Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
   >   Command returned non-zero exit code:
   >   `/opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php -f /home/admin/pl.com/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I checked the log file "system.log" and found following entry after I ran above command:

```
[2018-02-06 07:54:30] main.ERROR: /opt/alt/php70/usr/bin/php -f /home/admin/pl.com/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 52.0 MiB%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 52.0 MiBProxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec 52.0 MiB
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 56.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 56.0 MiB<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        .required {color: red;}
    </style>
</html><html>
    <style type="text/css">
        .required {color: red;}
    </style>
</html> [] []
```

Can someone help me on this. Am I missing something in my steps to set it in production mode.

Comment: have you check server php/apache error log?

Comment: No I did not check it. I tried look where this log can be found. But could not find it. Can you please tell me where can i find this log file. I have a reseller account and I have hosted this site in a account within my reseller account.

Comment: @Devanshu you may check logs in <magento_root>/var/log directory 
check system.log and exception.log

Comment: Try to run your command with display errors option, like: `php -d display_errors=on bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vvv`

Comment: @Magento2Learner Thanks for reply. The exception.log is empty in my case.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Thanks for this tip. running deploy command with display error did not show any error. However I ran the production mode setting command as "php -d display_errors=on bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv". This gave me following trace on shell:   Fatal error: Interface 'Magecomp\Productattachments\Controller\AbstractController\ProductattachLoaderInterface' not found in /home/admin/pl.com/app/code/Magecomp/Productattachments/Controller/AbstractController/ProductattachmentsLoader.php on line 9

Comment: are you using any third party theme or module which is adding any custom css ?

Comment: Seems like third party extension error. @Magento2Learner You are right in highlighting that.